# Web Chat application - how to persist data properly?

Tags: websocket, signalr, chat

We are currently implementing a simple chat app that allows users to create conversations and exchange messages.

Our basic setup involves AngularJS on the front-end and SignalR hub on the back end.  It works like this:

1. Client app opens a Websockets connection to our real-time service (based on SignalR) and subscribes to chat updates
2. User starts sending messages. For each new message, client app calls HTTP API to send it
3. The API stores the message in the database and notifies our real-time service that there is a new message
4. Real-time service pushes the message via Websockets to subscribed Clients

However, we noticed that opening up so many HTTP connections for each new message may not be a good idea, so we were wondering if Websockets should be used to both send and receive messages?

The new setup would look like this:

1. Client app opens a Websockets connection with real-time service
2. User starts sending messages. Client app pushes the messages to real-time service using Websockets
3. Real-time service picks up the message, notifies our persistence service it needs to be stored, then delivers the message to other subscribed Clients
4. Persistence service stores the message

Which of these options is more typical when setting up an efficient and performant chat system? Thanks!

Comment: SignalR is built for bidirectional communication; why **not** leverage the open WebSocket connection instead of creating another HTTP request?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a different http or Web API to persist message. Persist it in the hub method that is broadcasting the message. You can use async methods in the hub, create async tasks to save the message.

Using a different persistence API then calling signalr to broadcase isn't efficient, and why dublicate all the efforts?